# Running multiple apps on the same subdomain with different IIS servers

Tags: ssl, iis, subdomain

I have a subdomain, let's say it's `abc.def.com`. Currently, I set up this subdomain with the SSL cert. on the IIS server, we can call this server is `server-A`. Under `server-A` I have more than one app running for each path. For example, `app-A` running on `abc.def.com/app-A`, `app-B` running on `abc.def.com/app-B`.

I have another IIS server (we can call it `server-B`), and I would like to use the same domain as `server-A`. And then run the apps on `server-B` using the domain from `server-A`, for example, we have `app-C` in `server-B`, and I want to apply `abc.def.com/app-C` for that app.

Does it sound possible? if yes, any guidelines I can try to achieve?

BTW, the SSL cert. is not a wildcard SSL, it's a specific SSL to that `abc.def.com` subdomain.

Comment: You can install a server certificate anywhere you like, so I see nothing wrong on what you want to set up. But how to distribute traffic to these two servers based on the applications (`app-A`/`app-B`/`app-C`) can be your next question, and people usually use reverse proxy.

Comment: You're right, I forgot about the reverse proxy. It works after I applied the SSL for both IIS servers and using reverse proxy with a match pattern to other IIS. Do you think there will be any side effects?